# Simple PHP gallery with DirectoryIterator

Tags: php, iterator, directory, gallery

I'm trying to build a simple gallery from a directory. I have this scenario:

```
- 2013                <-- directory
  -- Album 1          <-- directory
     -- image1.jpg    <-- file
     -- image2.jpg
     -- image3.jpg
  -- Album 2
     -- image1.jpg
- 2014
  -- Album 1
     -- image1.jpg
     -- image2.jpg
  -- Album 2
     -- image1.jpg
```

I tought that [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) can simply do this, but I can't figure out to get it work and call the functions.

So far:

Print a list of years

```
function listYears(){
$basefolder = "gallery/";
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($basefolder) as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    if($fileInfo->isFile()) continue;
    echo '<a href="index.php?year='. $fileInfo->getFilename() .'">'. $fileInfo->getFilename() .'</a><br>';
}
true;
}
```

Print a list of the Albums in the selected year

```
function listAlbums($year){
$basefolder = 'gallery/'. $year;
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($basefolder) as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    if($fileInfo->isFile()) continue;
    echo '<a href="index.php?year='. $year .'&album='. $fileInfo->getFilename() .'"></a>';
}
true;
}
```

And finally get the images

```
function getImages($year,$album){
$basefolder = "gallery/";
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($basefolder) as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    if($fileInfo->isDir()) continue;
    echo '<img src="'. $basefolder.''. $year.'/'. $album .'/'. $fileInfo->getFilename() .'">';
}
true;
}
```

So, i'm trying to do something like

```
www.site.com/gallery.php?year=2014
```

and view the albums of 2014, so you can choose

```
www.site.com/gallery.php?year=2014&album=album_name
```

and view the photos from that album.

Even better would be

```
www.site.com/gallery/2014/album_name
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use folioGallery It's a php photo gallery which uses your file system to generate gallery.

downlaod link for same : http://www.foliopages.com/php-jquery-ajax-photo-gallery-no-database

Comment: http://s30.postimg.org/upxs17669/image.jpg that's how looks from the iPad. Not good. I need a super simple thing without build-in lightbox.

Comment: OK, the PHP example is working but for i dont'n need that lightbox http://s11.postimg.org/6wpna5y9v/image.jpg